# XPCOM component DLL loads into Firefox, but then fails to register its class

Tags: c++, winapi, firefox, xpcom

I have an XPCOM component whose source when compiled, works fine on Linux, but does not work on Windows.  The DLL is clearly being loaded as expected by Firefox as revealed by the dependency walker program, but it appears never to be executed by it.

This is the command line I am using to compile it all:

```
[4/5] cxx: components\nsSoundSubsystem.cpp -> build\components\nsSoundSubsystem.cpp.2.o
15:44:31 runner ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\VC\\BIN\\CL.exe', '/nologo', '/MT', '/IE:\\src\\chunder\\clients\\xpcomextension\\build', '/IE:\\src\\chunder\\clients\\xpcomextension', '/IE:\\src\\chunder\\clients\\xpcomextension\\build\\components', '/IE:\\src\\chunder\\clients\\xpcomextension\\components', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\VC\\INCLUDE', '/IC:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v6.0A\\include', '/Ic:\\xulrunner-sdk\\include', '/DHAVE_XPCOM_CONFIG_H=1', '/DMOZ_NO_MOZALLOC', '/DWIN32', '/D_WINDOWS', '/D_USRDLL', '/DXP_WIN', '/DXP_WIN32', '/DXPCOM_GLUE_USE_NSPR', '..\\components\\nsSoundSubsystemModule.cpp', '/FC', '/c', '/Focomponents\\nsSoundSubsystemModule.cpp.2.o']
15:44:31 runner ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\VC\\BIN\\CL.exe', '/nologo', '/MT', '/IE:\\src\\chunder\\clients\\xpcomextension\\build', '/IE:\\src\\chunder\\clients\\xpcomextension', '/IE:\\src\\chunder\\clients\\xpcomextension\\build\\components', '/IE:\\src\\chunder\\clients\\xpcomextension\\components', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\VC\\INCLUDE', '/IC:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v6.0A\\include', '/Ic:\\xulrunner-sdk\\include', '/DHAVE_XPCOM_CONFIG_H=1', '/DMOZ_NO_MOZALLOC', '/DWIN32', '/D_WINDOWS', '/D_USRDLL', '/DXP_WIN', '/DXP_WIN32', '/DXPCOM_GLUE_USE_NSPR', '..\\components\\nsSoundSubsystem.cpp', '/FC', '/c', '/Focomponents\\nsSoundSubsystem.cpp.2.o']
nsSoundSubsystem.cpp
nsSoundSubsystemModule.cpp
[5/5] cxxshlib: build\components\nsSoundSubsystemModule.cpp.2.o build\components\nsSoundSubsystem.cpp.2.o -> build\components\chunder_x86.dll build\components\chunder_x86.dll.manifest build\components\chunder_x86.lib
15:44:32 runner ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\VC\\BIN\\LINK.exe', 'components\\nsSoundSubsystemModule.cpp.2.o', 'components\\nsSoundSubsystem.cpp.2.o', '/OUT:E:\\src\\chunder\\clients\\xpcomextension\\build\\components\\chunder_x86.dll', '/LIBPATH:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\VC\\LIB', '/LIBPATH:C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v6.0A\\lib', '/LIBPATH:c:\\xulrunner-sdk\\lib', 'xpcom.lib', 'xpcomglue_s_nomozalloc.lib', 'nspr4.lib', '/NOLOGO', '/MANIFEST', '/DLL', '/machine:I386', '/IMPLIB:components\\chunder_x86.lib']
   Creating library components\chunder_x86.lib and object components\chunder_x86.exp
15:44:33 runner ['C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v6.0A\\bin\\MT.exe', '/NOLOGO', '-manifest', 'E:\\src\\chunder\\clients\\xpcomextension\\build\\components\\chunder_x86.dll.manifest', '-outputresource:E:\\src\\chunder\\clients\\xpcomextension\\build\\components\\chunder_x86.dll;2']
```

I am at my wits' end, three days in this chase.

What am I doing wrong?  Alternatively, what can I do to help me debug the issue?

Additional info: I am using Firefox 4 to run the module, and the XULrunner 2.0 SDK to compile the module.  The interface from the XPT file registers itself just fine.

Comment: Additional information:  The module loads and then immediately unloads according to the Firefox NSPR log:

    [732140]: Loaded library C:\Users\Rudd-O\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\hob5ycuo.default\extensions\chunder@me.com\components\chunder_x86.dll (load lib)
    [732140]: Unloaded library C:\Users\Rudd-O\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\hob5ycuo.default\extensions\chunder@me.com\components\chunder_x86.dll

Comment: Additional information: the DLL shows, using dumpbin /exports, an NSModule entry point = _NSModule

Comment: Bug filed:  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=666450

Comment: Additional information: I have tried MSVC 10 and MSVC 9, both the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `nsNativeModuleLoader::LoadModule`, dependencies are not the problem here - failing dependencies would result in the library not loading in the first place, there wouldn't be anything to unload. There are two conditions under which the library will be unloaded: symbol `NSModule` is not defined or module version doesn't match. From your description, the former is the problem, it should really be `NSModule` and not `_NSModule`. So I guess that you are using something other than `NSMODULE_DEFN()` macro. See http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/xpcom/sample/nsSampleModule.cpp for an example of a correct module definition. Should my guess be incorrect please show us your module definition code.

Comment: Symbol NSModule is defined to be _NSModule.  It works on Linux.  Ideas?

Comment: This is in the code: NSMODULE_DEFN(nsSoundSubsystemModule) = &kSoundSubsystemModule;

Comment: I *am* using the macro def in question.  :-(

Comment: @Rudd-O: Weird, this macro resolves into `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) mozilla::Module const *const NSModule = ...`. If I put that into a CPP file and compile with the same command line options as you `dumpbin` shows `NSModule` as the only export, not `_NSModule`.

Comment: The export was NSModule = _NSModule.  Not just _NSModule.

Comment: Also, I would like to add that I solved the problem by hardcoding the version member in the module structure to 2 instead of mozilla::Module::kVersion which was 1.

Comment: @Rudd-O: Sounds like your SDK version doesn't match your Firefox version - probably not the release version? Note that `kVersion` kept increasing with every Firefox version, you will need to recompile your module with the newest SDK every time.